# Should I use PageObject pattern or should I just copy-paste selectors & step by step actions in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I am currently planning a Selenium-testing strategy for our medium-big project (50 devs, 10 qa). I thought of using the PageObject pattern to create a nice abstraction and many reusable components.

However, another colleague believes that due to the nature of the tests, they should be as simple as possible, and copy-pasted all-over the place, due to their perishable nature.

We are both very skilled in OOP and clean-code, we know that PageObject pattern is the way to go, however, I can't foresee how it behaves for a big project (let's say 20000 selenium tests)

**My arguments towards using PageObject:**

- following the abstraction of the product
- PageObject is necessary in order not to end up with an maintainable mess
- easy response to wide-changes in the product

**His arguments towards copy-paste driven testing:**

- PageObject requires at least medium-level programming skills and concepts, while our tests will be mostly written by our QA eng, with limited dev experience
- tests are perishable. they have a very short lifecycle
- an abstraction introduces complexity and will become extremely hard to maintain at a level of 20000 tests
- an abstraction may deviate from user's actual behavior
- whoever wants to write tests (mostly QA) must understand the abstraction, rather than just use the basic selenium commands. also, the selenium testing codebase may become a project on its own, and you may even want to make unit tests for it :))

**The question would be**: Given the big size of the project, what approach would be feasible?

Comment: Why "very short lifecycle"? why not keep them to check nothing is broken when adding new feature?

Comment: your colleague is absolutely correct..when the project is big..then PageObjects do not go well for automation..and at the end it becomes lot of code for maintainenance..haphazard..whereas i would suggest a hybrid framework

Answer (score 1):

At scale a combination of the two would be best.  There will only ever be a limited number of elements on any page you are testing.  These elements will all have locators, and will be used in some combination to achieve your workflows.  Having page objects that define those elements and their locators will help immensely with maintaining your tests efficiently as it will avoid duplication of elements and make propagating small changes to the selectors much quicker.

However, having all/most of your logic for a project that big inside the page objects will soon become very complicated to maintain, and after while people will end up duplicating things anyway.  Leaving the logic in your tests, rather than the page objects will probably be simpler, even with the duplication being an overhead.  This approach would give some of the benefits of page objects without a lot of the complexity and overheads that it sounds like your teams may not be well equipped to deal with.

If anything, working in this way would be simpler for your QA's than working without any page objecting.  Once a wrapper for a page is written (a lot of which could be done up front) they will not have to do things like choosing selectors and following a naming convention for elements etc.

Obviously the ideal solution would be for your QAs to be comfortable understanding a (hopefully) well thought out and consistent abstraction pattern that would sit on top of this, but if that isn't an option then fair enough.

I have worked before with a layer between my page objects and my step definitions (I was using cucumber at the time) that was called the business logic layer or something similar to that.  This layer provided methods that abstracted away some of the more common user activities (e.g. logging in, navigating to pages), giving a way to avoid code duplication for the most frequently used activities, without trying to abstract all of the other code from the tests.